# Is there a dropdown select and input combined field for grid cells in ag-Grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am looking for `cellEditor` in ag-Grid which allows for a dropdown select combined with input so users can add custom values in addition to selecting it from the dropdown. Is this something ag-Grid currently support?

Comment: If you use React, there is an example of using React-Select in agGrid for that purpose :https://codesandbox.io/s/aggrid-reactselect-uq0bk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is something not supported by ag-Grid, as it is beyond the scope of what ag-Grid does.

However, you can create your custom cell editor components, as specified by the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/#react-cell-editing). They have made a demo application made using React and ag-grid, with the use of custom cell editor components over [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ytGGgzoPuGOOtaW9) too. As for the function of the dropdown-select, you can import that particular library (or write it natively yourself) into the custom cell editor component to ensure that your cell editor has that functionality.

Comment: is there any other method to do so because I have the same question but in my scenario grid should show label only and value should be different for selected.